# How to add border to row on jumping to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some table like this

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="column" id="1-row">
        <td>
            <span id="1">1</span>
            <a href="#1">(link)</a>
        </td>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>username</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column" id="2-row">
        <td>
            <span id="2">2</span>
            <a href="#2">(link)</a>
        </td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>username</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to add border with style outline: 'thick solid black', for example, to first row when I jumping to page by clicking http://www.thiswebpage/#1

Answer (score 0):

Use the css `:target` selector

```css
a {
  color:black
}

* {
  text-align: center;
}

div#myTarget:target, div#myOtherTarget:target {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myTarget">Click to target #myTarget</a><br>
<a href="#myOtherTarget">Click to target #myOtherTarget</a>
<br><br>
<div id="myTarget">#myTarget</div>
<div id="myOtherTarget">#myOtherTarget</div>
```